# Nginx error rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting - what's wrong?

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, internals

I'm getting this:

2020/06/12 20:43:58 [error] 3266#3266: *39 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/home/panel/front/qcnet24-front/index.html", client: 195.x.x.136, server: my-app, request: "GET /register HTTP/1.1", host: "vps-866691.vps.ovh.net"

My configuration of nginx.conf is:

```
server{
                listen 0.0.0.0:80;
                server_name my-app;
                root /home/panel/front/qcnet24-front;
                #error_page 404 /home/panel/front/qcnet24-front/index.html;

                location / {
                        index index.html;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /home/panel/front/qcnet24-front/index.html;
                }

                location /images {
                        alias /home/panel/Pictures;
                }

                location /api {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;
                }

                location /login {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/login;
                }
    }
```

}

Comment: The last argument of [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive can be an URI, named location or HTTP error code, but not an absolute/relative file path/name. Replace `/home/panel/front/qcnet24-front/index.html` argument of `try_files` directive with simply `/index.html` (lets make it an URI).